# CartThrob Not Saving Custom Member Data to Profile:Edit

Tags: members, cartthrob, member-details

When someone checkouts with CartThrob a new member is added to the member_profiles channel using Profile:Edit. However, not all the information is coming across to the member entry.

At checkout all the customer_info is there in the CT debugger (http://cl.ly/MG0q).

We use this on checkout.php:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form
create_user="yes"
group_id="5"
class="form"
error_handling="inline"
return="membership/order_info"}
```

But when the transaction finalises most of the customer_info resets to 0 except for the {phone} field. And that’s what ends up in the ‘Member Profile’ channel too. (http://cl.ly/MEed)

All the correct customer info from the join.php is in the ‘order’ channel but the member_profiles channel only has the email and phone fields. We have the member fields mapped correctly in CT and are telling it to use Profile:Edit.

Our full add to cart/save customer info form, join.php, is here http://pastebin.com/wJi4QeHM

Any ideas?

EE 2.5.3
CT 2.2.2
Profile:Edit 1.0.8

Comment: Have you managed to get this resolved? If not have you tried the latest version of Profile:Edit (1.0.9)?

Comment: Yes we are using v1.0.9 of Profile:Edit. It has made no difference to our issue. And with no support from the developer we are having to manually fill in the member details ourselves using the email confirmation data. So buying Profile:Edit for this scenario has been a total waste of money.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there's a [known issue](http://mightybigrobot.com/forums/viewthread/7599/) with the Profile:Edit addon not saving custom fields. That could be the culprit.

> There’s a problem caused by the 2.5.4 update. Specifically, safecracker entry submissions will partially fail, resulting in custom fields not getting filled in.
>
> Problem is mod.profile.php at line 878 - the exp_security_hashes has changed in structure and no longer has an ip_address column.
>
> Turning off Secure Forms is a workaround.

Disabling secure form processing is generally a bad idea, but it's worth a try in your dev environment so you can verify whether that's the problem. If it is then you'll probably have to wait for a fix to be released.

Comment: Hi Dom. We are currently only using EE2.5.3 and already have secure forms turned off in our dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related but I have a similar, non-CartThrob related, issue posted here...

[Are custom member fields not functional in the registration form if the setting for "field visible in registration page" is set to "No"](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/are-custom-member-fields-not-functional-in-the-registration-form-if-the-setting)

Data for custom member fields are not being saved for pending members who have just signed up.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here http://mightybigrobot.com/forums/viewthread/7599/ this issue seems to be solved. Did this have an effect on the above problem? Askin for this update because I am working on a site with Cartthrob and Profile:edit.

For the moderators here, I wanted my post to be a comment, not an answer, did not know how to do that.