# Are custom member fields not functional in the registration form if the setting for "field visible in registration page" is set to "No"

Tags: forms, member-details, registration

I have a number of custom member fields setup to store "yes" or "no" settings. They are used for form inputs for checkbox fields. I don't want them visible on the standard Exp Eng profile pages or on the standard Exp Eng Registration page because that would be confusing to the user and they might enter incorrect values in the fields.

In the Exp Eng documentation there is this...

> Is this field visible in registration page?
>
> When set to “yes”, the field will be available in the public member registration form.

For these fields in question I have them set to "no" for the above setting. My question is, will the above setting also "deactivate" that custom field on a Registration page, even if I make the field available in the code of the form?

I have a custom registration page that I setup in a member profile template group that uses these input fields but after someone has submitted the form and completed the member signup none of the selections that use those fields come through.

From the point of view of the person signing up they are making selections to signup for email newsletters but after they are registered none of those subscriptions choices were saved.

There may be another issue with a javascript routine but that works fine on other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, those fields will not be functional in your front-end registration forms either. You need to set them to "yes" for that setting.

If you're wanting to hide those fields from the user in their EE profile edit page, then set the previous option regarding making it available in the public profile to "no."

Comment: Stephen, thanks. I will probably have to go with the User module for registration then because I don't want someone landing on Exp Eng's built-in registration page somehow and being able to see those fields.